# Network card shuts down when stressed

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

I have a network card that functions fine with light use, but quits functioning after heavy use. I replaced it with a brand new one and still have the same issue, also updated drivers. It is a wired D-Link card.

The Internet seems fine for a small amount of web browsing but when I run a bandwidth test it starts out fast and slows quickly until the card completely quits; I have a constant ping of the gateway going while I run this and it starts timing-out after a couple seconds into the speed test. The card will stay on and the data light on it still flashes some but I cannot ping the gateway or anything else until the computer is rebooted. After this happens (before doing the reboot), if I try to disable the interface in Network Connections the window freezes up.

Anyone had a similar issue or have any other suggestions/ideas for narrowing down this problem?

**Update:** I had previously said that this problem did not exist in safe-mode. That must have been a fluke that allowed it to work once because it does not work in safe-mode either.

The computer in question has both a card (PCI, I think) and an integrated NIC, one used for a LAN (the integrated) and one used for accessing the Internet (the card). When I switched the two ethernet cables and swapped their corresponding static IP configurations, everything seemed to work fine.

Is it possible that the combination of the card and either the router or switch that it is hooked up to are having some kind of issue? Why would it [seem to] work fine after switching them? I suppose the only way to find out for sure is to try different hardware but I can't mess with that currently.

Comment: Are you running anti-virus software?

Comment: No, I mentioned that it was turned off but no, there isn't even any on that computer.

Comment: I think you should change your title if this has been ruled to no longer be a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

> "I have a network card that functions fine with light use, but quits
>   functioning after heavy use. I replaced it with a brand new one and
>   still have the same issue, also updated drivers. It is a wired D-Link
>   card."

Its probably not the network card.

> "The Internet seems fine for a small amount of web browsing but when I
>   run a bandwidth test it starts out fast and slows quickly until the
>   card completely quits; I have a constant ping of the gateway going
>   while I run this and it starts timing out after a couple seconds into
>   the speed test"

Might be the gateway - unless other systems work fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, yes all other systems work fine (in standard boot mode).

Comment: Tried swapping cables then?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that it has to be some kind of software issue since it works fine when booted into safe mode.

Comment: Hm, then my initial guesses are off. Leaving the answer here, in case someone else ends up with a similar issue tho.

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion would be to look at the processes that are running when the network stops responding.  Then, boot into Safe Mode and look at those processes.  Cross-reference the processes, and the ones that are not running in Safe Mode might be the culprits.

If you determine that all of the processes are the same or are neutral to the problem, then you should look at the services that are running.

Here's a description of Safe Mode With Networking for Windows 7 from Microsoft:

> Starts Windows in safe mode and includes the network drivers and
>   services needed to access the Internet or other computers on your
>   network.

I would think it will be a startup program causing this problem, so look at what's starting up by clicking 'Start' and then type 'msconfig' in the search box and look under the startup tabs:

http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking I would need to do and this is good information, I will post back when I find the solution.